# Why does the spacing for tall fractions in enumerate list depend on order?

Tags: enumerate, line-spacing, enumitem, displaystyle

It seems the lineskip is being ignored when the dfrac is placed at the end of the list. Why is this the case?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\textbf{\Alph{enumii}.}}
\setlength{\lineskip}{4pt}

\newenvironment{myenum}
{\begin{enumerate}[labelsep=2.5mm, align=left,leftmargin=*]
    \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}
{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item blahblah
\begin{myenum}
\item $4.25 - c > 200$
\item $4.25 + c \leq 200$
\item $\dfrac{c}{4.25} > 200$ %%% when this is placed at the end of the list, the spacing before it gets reduced
\item $4.25c \leq 200$
\item $4.25c > 200$
\end{myenum}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\lineskip` and `\parskip` are low-level parameters that aren't even mentioned in the user guide of the `enumitem` package. If you reset these parameters anyway, it's strictly at your own risk. Setting `itemsep=0pt` as one of the options of the `myenum` environment (and skip the four `\setlength` instructions) may be all you really need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the line before. `\leq` has more depth than a simple `<`. Compare:

[image]

[image]

Add a `\strut` or a `\vphantom{\leq}` to the D.-line.